# Change file names using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have many files and I want to change these names as a file for file_1-1 until I reach to file40 for file_8-5.

I write this code but it deletes all files and converts the last file to file1.

```
    pwd
    for i in {1..8}     
    do
    for j in {1..5}    
    do
    for k in {1..40}    
    do
    (cd ./prof/ && mv file_$i-$j.dat file$k.dat)
    done
    done
    done
```

Comment: It does not delete the files, it moves all of them to `pixel1.ps`. Althouth I doubt it can work with the `cd ./prof` each time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess you need to go only once in `prof/`. Then, you can compute `k` from `i` and `j`. In bash:

```
cd prof
for i in {1..8}     
do
    for j in {1..5}    
    do
        k=$(( ($i-1) * 5 + $j ))
        mv pixel_$i-$j.ps pixel$k.ps
    done
done
```

Comment: It did not produce the correct files.

Comment: Do you have files `pixel_1-1` ... `pixel_8-5` in folder `prof/` ?

Comment: Yes, as pixel_1-1,....,pixel_1-5, pixel_2-1,....,pixel_2-5 and so on.

Comment: Is your shell `bash` ? You can know with `echo "$SHELL"`

Comment: I updated the post to propose alternative methods to compute `k`

Comment: The outputs 24 pictures, not 40 and these 24 pictures, not correct files.

Comment: Indeed, I've just fixed

Comment: My shell is /bin/csh

Comment: Okay, it works now but (* 5)  is numbers of j, for I want to change it?

Comment: I do not understand "now but (* 5) is numbers of j, for I want to change it"

Comment: I ask about multiply by 5 in  (k=$(( ($i-1) * 5 + $j ))) is the maximum number of j, if  j in {1..100} so I do (k=$(( ($i-1) * 100 + $j )))?.

Comment: yes, indeed. You multiply `$i-1` by the maximal value of `$j`